# Edit css of a site loaded in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to edit a class ".game" to have 'top' in css set to 0 from X number that is on this site: http://oldschool1.runescape.com/j1

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src='http://www.jagex.com/js/jquery/jquery_1_7.js'></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script>
document.getElementByClass("game").top = 0;
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
 <div> 
    <object type="text/html" data="http://oldschool1.runescape.com/j1" width="785" height="535" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue"></object>
    <br>
    <object type="text/html" data="http://oldschool1.runescape.com/j1" width="785" height="535" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue"></object>
    <br>
    <object type="text/html" data="http://oldschool1.runescape.com/j1" width="785" height="535" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue"></object>
    </div>
 <button type='button'>Scroll</button>
</body>
</html>
```

if you inspect elements you can find a div with class game and there is parametr 'top' in css which i want set to 0. I've tried to work it out for 3hours but i have no more ideas how to do it.

Comment: Where are .game elements?!

Comment: document.getElementByClass(''game").style.top = yourvalue

Comment: @theinarasu There is no such function. It's `getElementsByClassName`. But it returns a `NodeList`, so you have to index it before you can set properties on the elements.

Comment: @Barmar thanks bro for point out , its suppose id  
document.getElementById(''game").style.top = yourvalue ...or can use as document.getElementsByClassName("game")[0].style.top = 0;

Comment: You can't access cross domain site due to same origin policy

Comment: I have updated the answer to wait for objects to load. please check if helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have jquery, so you should be able to do something like this

```
$('.game').css('top','0');
```

Answer (score 0):

On the link you provided there is no element with game class. I checked with jQuery

```
var ele= $('.game'); // ele is null meaning empty
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment, and someone else already made this comment.

Answer (score 0):

When using pure JavaScript remind these:

1. Change getElementsByClass to getElementsByClassName
2. Move the script to the end of page and let element to be rendered
3. Use `.style.top` instead of `.top`

However I rewrote the script using Jquery to avoid above-mentioned mistakes. Even using Jquery, you have to wait for ***object*** content to load and also extract the content of object to work with. You can not work with elements of object directly from the parent page.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src='http://www.jagex.com/js/jquery/jquery_1_7.js'></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
 <div> 
    <object type="text/html" data="http://oldschool1.runescape.com/j1" width="785" height="535" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue"></object>
    <br>
    <object type="text/html" data="http://oldschool1.runescape.com/j1" width="785" height="535" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue"></object>
    <br>
    <object type="text/html" data="http://oldschool1.runescape.com/j1" width="785" height="535" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue"></object>
    </div>
 <button type='button'>Scroll</button>
</body>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("object").each(function(){
         waitToLoad($(this))
  })
 
  function waitToLoad(obj){
      obj.on('load',function(){
      $(this).contents().css("top","0"); //Don't Forget contents();
      })
   }
</script>
  
</html>
```

Comment: window load is only parent window...not window in object and that window is cross domain

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the code to wait for objects content.

Comment: It's still the same. If you run it in Mozilla Firefox, and delete ads etc with ublock orion, you will see a gap between a panel and gamescreen, i would like to remove that gap, when i do it locally it works but then the game won't load properly because it needs to be from the company servers etc.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/TysIcZ4.png This is where you find .game div and the top, and it should look like this: http://i.imgur.com/SHragqg.png  i can do it manually but i would really want to do it with code to not constantly change it

Comment: Sorry I don't see those screens when I run code snippet. Perhaps you have logged in the game or something else? this is what I see: http://imgur.com/DKWyI6H

Comment: If you may, click "Free player? Play now!" remmember to run with mozilla firefox, other browsers dont support java i think. Well at least for me, and i deleted adverts above gamescreen with ublock

Comment: You have no access to the content of "object" after they start playing except you run a periodic function to get the its content every seconds.

Comment: And how could i do that? I'm a beginner, never tried that but i really need this. Could you be able to show me how to do it?

Comment: Please search for JavaScript setInterval. Hoever it is not efficient solution for this purpose.

Comment: setInterval(function(){$('.input_submit').trigger('click')},680000); 

i've got this from my previous script. So instead of $(input_submit) i would have to set your function so it loads per 1 sec?

Comment: Do not repeat whole function with event listener. Just repeat this part: `$(this).contents().css("top","0");`

Answer (score 0):

getElementByClass is not a javascript method. Use getElementsByClassName().

```
document.getElementsByClassName("CLASS_NAME")[0].style.top = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you are using jquery you could do something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("game");
```

You now have a javasript object so you could easily do:

```
$.each(el, function(){
    $(this).css("top", "0");
```

});

This would of course apply the CSS style to all of the elements with class = "game" but if you wanted to you could easily filter this by using an if conditional.

Comment: Why do you need `.each`? Just use `$(".game").css("top", 0);`. jQuery automatically when you assign things.